# How to get the SQL script of Import task

Tags: sql-server-express

I am using the Import feature in SQL Express 2008

When I get to the end of the wizard, I can run it, but how do I found out the SQL code so I can run this script via automation tools (such as a bat file)?

Answer (score 3):

The Import and Export Wizard generates a SSIS package (dtsx) for you. You can use the command line utility `dtexec.exe` or `dtexecui.exe` to automate the import process in a batch file.

You can also inspect the SSIS package inside SQL Server Data Tools.

Comment: I did a search on my machine for `.dtsx` and found the folder but, nothing has been modified since 2012! Where is the file you mean?

Comment: In the last step of the Import Export Wizard you are able to save the package or to run it...

Comment: ah... I see..... You may have missed my question which states `SQL Express` :( There is a note in SQL express saying something similar to "to save the script you need to upgrade to Standard, Enterprise etc"

Comment: Indeed... sorry :-) Do you have access to the full Management Studio, you could then connect to SQLExpress 2008 instance...

Comment: Yes, I can perform a manual import within Managment Studio, but as you spotted, my goal is to automate the import daily

Comment: It's just to get the SSIS package. As far as i know SQL Server Express with Advanced Services (also free) should include dtexec.exe...

Comment: Where is the SSIS package stored? I can find .dtsx files but a search for `.SSIS` returns nothing

Comment: As said.. if you use the full version of Sql Server Management Studio, then you can save your import task in the last step of the Import Export Wizard to disk - you choose where to save it. After that you can run the package with dtexec.exe...

Answer (score 1):

You won't get SQL scirpt, because MSSQL "Import and Export Data" tools doesn't offer that. But you can do your self by using "BULK INSERT" mssql command. Behind the scene MSSQL "Import and Export Data" tools do that.

Here is reference using BULK INSERT: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Tutorial using BULK INSERT: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/